# Can you replicate Clojure's (partition) or Scala's sliding() functions with Guava?

Tags: java, scala, clojure, guava

I have a list that I want to split in a manner similar to the `(partition sz step col)` method of Clojure or the `IterableLike.sliding(size: Int, step: Int)` function of Scala.  Specifically, given a list like:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

I want to be able to iterate over the sub-lists like:

```
(1, 2), (2, 3)
```

In Clojure this would be done with:

```
(partition 2 1 (1, 2, 3))
```

and with Scala it would be:

```
val it = Vector(1, 2, 3).sliding(2)
```

However I do not have such a luxury and I'm hoping to avoid having to roll my own.  Guava has a partition method that comes close, but doesn't offer the overlap.  Googling has been fruitless as well.  Does such a method exist or will I have to roll my own?

Comment: if no-one knows of anything better you could merge two guava partitions, where the second is from a sequence with one element dropped...

Comment: Wouldn't you need *size* partitions?  Good idea though.

Comment: You can use map, something like: `(map (fn [x y] '(x,y)) lst (rest lst))`

Comment: I've currently rolled my own by implementing Iterator<E> and adding a nextWindow() method, but I'm still curious if this is possible with Guava.  It seems like it should be able to do it, but there is a parameter missing from one of the `partition()` methods.

Comment: What's the use case?  Guava doesn't have anything like this, but we might consider adding it if we heard the use case.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: The typical use case is computing the moving average: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

Comment: @LouisWasserman For me the use case is that I'm trying to process a set of locations, i.e.:

    Canada,Ontario,Toronto

My data structure has a parent->child relationship, so for me it is easier to process the data in parent->child pairs via a moving window, so partitioning would allow me to process (Canada, Ontario) and then (Ontario, Toronto).  Logic remains the same.  As paradigmatic mentioned, moving averages is another one.  Bioinfomatics use this as well, see: http://scipher.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/simple-sliding-window-iterator-in-python/

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'll accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guava doesn't have anything like this right now, but if you file an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/list), we can discuss adding it.

For myself, I would use an `ArrayDeque` to store the running window, but that wouldn't make sense for a library method.

Answer (score 2):

Guava does not have this, but its `AbstractIterator` will probably make "rolling your own" easier.

There might already be a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/list) filed for it; if not, please feel free.